# Is it possible to integrate React components with existing Wordpress websites?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

as the title suggests I was wondering if it's possible to integrate a component built in React with an existing Wordpress website. The component is only about 80 lines long, consisting of a  with an image. The component itself was built as part of a create-react-app project. Any insights greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can check this link https://dev.to/julbrs/how-to-use-react-inside-a-wordpress-application-49i

Answer (score 0):

What is the react component your using if its available in html5 like bootstrap components for example its unnecessary to use react app and craco together due to multiple issues in polyfills and webpack so its harder to maintain if your looking for something simpler it still works and has around 85kgithub users in 2022 .
https://github.com/dilanx/craco

examples of recent issues in stackoverflow
[craco-does-not-work-properly-with-react-scripts5-0-0][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234041/craco-does-not-work-properly-with-react-scripts5-0-0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, React can be used with WordPress, where the content on the front-end built with React is managed by WordPress CMS using the WP Rest API.

Just use the WP Rest API. Hope it helps.